# Determining average values from excel sheet in python

Tags: python, excel

Please can someone help me with this, I am trying to find the average value of the values from B2:B1500 which was extracted from excel into python environment but i am stuck. This is the code i have written so far.

```
wb=xl.load_workbook("J:/Data/T0444CH1.xlsx")
type(wb)
ws = wb.active
tuple(ws['B2':'B1500'])
for rowOfCellObjects in ws['B2':'B1500']:
    for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
        def avg(cellObj):
            return float(sum(cellObj))/len(cellObj)
average = sum(cellObj)/len(cellObj)
```

This is the error i am getting

```
average = sum(cellObj)/len(cellObj)
TypeError: 'Cell' object is not iterable
```

Comment: You are trying to define a function inside of a double loop, which is not a good idea

Comment: This code is broken in many ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, in this case, is that `cellObj` is not a list or something that Python can summate, it is a variable. Also, another problem is that you never called your average function, which does exactly the same thing the last line does, and will also result in the same error, so you could either use that or delete that 
(I recommend deleting it).

If you want to still use the `sum` function, then you can create a list of all the values. In this case you could do this:

```
wb=xl.load_workbook("J:/Data/T0444CH1.xlsx")
type(wb)
ws = wb.active
tuple(ws['B2':'B1500'])
#Our List Of cells
cells = []
for rowOfCellObjects in ws['B2':'B1500']:
    for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
        cells.append(cellObj)
average = sum(cells)/len(cells)
```

If you wanted to reduce the memory usage by just using a variable, you could do this:

```
wb=xl.load_workbook("J:/Data/T0444CH1.xlsx")
type(wb)
ws = wb.active
tuple(ws['B2':'B1500'])
#Our Totals
counter = 0
total = 0.0
for rowOfCellObjects in ws['B2':'B1500']:
    for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
      total+=float(cellObj)
      counter+=1
average = total/counter
```

Note: I haven't tested these solutions.